# decimal value with . automatically transform to ,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, culture

I am having many models which contain properties type double like this one:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public double val { get; set; }
}
```

I get the val value like 2.875

However, when i pass to my view, I got the value 2,875, the . of the 2.875 is transformed to a ,

Same things happens back when I got the . in my view, it is transform to a . in my controller, which crash my program

I am in France, but I am having a us chrome language and a windows in english, the program that I am making is a multi language ( en, fr, es), I think it is something to do with culture but don' t know how to set it up so I have control over what is displayed. Any indications or direction on the direction where i should look for ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set the culture in the web.config file? - e.g. `<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>`

Comment: Hello Stephens, thanks for your answer, I forgot to mention that the application is a multi-language app, does it good practice to put the parameter directly in the webconfig ? Thanks

Comment: Then you can do `<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>` and the language will be automatically setted to the user preference language sent to the server.

Comment: Hi CodeNotFound, it makes things a bit clearer now, how can I check / set the user preference language sent to the server ? if i set the user culture to en then all the decimals both from the client and server will be . right ?